How does area of a closed shape change with respect to perimeter?
I am playing around with the idea of finding the change in a closed shapes' area with respect to its' perimeter. I am aware that there can be no Area as a function of perimeter, since it would not give unique solution (for example, a perimeter of $2\pi$ could refer to a circle with $A=\pi$ or a square with $A =\frac{\pi^2}{4}$). However, I was hoping to get a function which shows $\frac{dA}{dp}$ if you know the equation of the closed shape. My question is, if possible, how can I improve my answer below? At the moment, it does not seem satisfying to me.
Here is what I have so far:
For a closed shape, it seems more natural to define it in polar coordinates, such that a closed shape can defined to have bounds $r(\theta)$. With that in mind, it can easily be found by a change of coordinates that $$\frac{dA(\theta)}{d\theta}=\frac{1}{2}(r(\theta))^2 $$ and $$\frac{dp(\theta)}{d\theta}=\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}$$ from here, you can get that $$\frac{dA}{dp}=\frac{r^2}{2\sqrt{r^2+(r'^2)}}$$ which is a function of theta. Now I am a bit stumped, since this actually doesn't seem to give me any information when applying it to any specific case. For example, if my shape is defined by $r=\sin(\theta)$, and I plug into this into what I have, I get back that $$\frac{dA}{dp}=\frac{(\sin\theta)^2}{2\sqrt{(\sin\theta)^2+(\cos\theta)^2}}=\frac{(\sin\theta)^2}{2}$$
So now what? This doesn't answer my question "if I change the perimeter of $r=\sin\theta$, how does its area change?", since the answer is a function of theta, not of $A$ or $p$. What can I do to get a more satisfying answer?

If your shape is a balanced set defined by $r(\theta)$, how is its area a function of $\theta$, $A(\theta)$?

I am not entirely sure of what you are asking, but you might want to look up the co-area formula and its applications (e.g., Example 13.4 of Sets of Finite
Perimeter and Geometric Variational Problems by Maggi).

@Al.G. I'm not sure if I can properly answer your question, but $A(\theta)$ comes from the fact that area enclosed generally is $$A = \int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}rdrd\theta$$ where r is a function of theta, so by extension A is a function of theta. I suppose with set bounds this becomes a constant, but this was my thinking anyways.

Uhm $$A=\iint_S1\cdot dxdy=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{R(\theta)}r\cdot drd\theta$$ for a set $S=\left{ (r,\theta):r<R(\theta),0<\theta<2\pi\right}$ (I believe that's the set you have in mind, right?). So $\theta$ does not leak anywhere, and neither $S$ nor $A$ are functions of $\theta$? Or probably I do not understand what you mean by $dr/d\theta$.

Your application of the chain rule doesn't make sense. $A$ and $p$ are both definite integrals from $0$ to $2\pi$, not functions of $\theta$.
